# Can not resolve method 'findViewById(int)'

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I'm having a trouble with `findViewByid` but I can't find where the problem is.

Here's my `FirstFragment` class code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "first";

private WebView mWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
 }

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondefragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


 }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to do this in onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
   View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondefragment, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
   progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

   WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

   return view;


}
```

Comment: What exactly is your error? Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: i replaced my oncreateView with yours but it says missing return statement,  i added:     `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondefragment, container, false);`  but it opens the webpage on the phone's default webbrowser, thanks for your time

Comment: it still opens in android default browser :/

Comment: fixed it adding  `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); ` :)

Comment: It seems unrelated to your initial question.

Answer (score 35):

`Fragment` doesn't provide the`findViewById()` method.  This is provided in `Activity` or `View`.  When implementing a `Fragment` you don't inflate your views in `onCreate()` (like you normally do in an `Activity`.)  Instead, you do it in `onCreateView()` and you need to use the inflated root `View` to find the ID within the layout you inflated.

Answer (score 7):

`getActivity().findViewById()` works. However, this isn't a good practice because the fragment may be *reused* in another activity.

The recommended way for this is to define an *interface*.

- The interface should contain methods by which the fragment needs to communicate with its parent activity.

  ```
  public interface MyInterfcae {
      void showTextView();
  }
  ```
- Then your activity implements that Interface.

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterfcae {
      @Override
      public void showTextView(){
          findViewById(R.id.textview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
  }
  ```
- In that fragment grab a reference to the interface.

  ```
  MyInterface mif = (MyInterface) getActivity();
  ```
- Call a method.

  ```
  mif.showTextView();
  ```

This way, the fragment and the activity are fully decoupled and every activity which implements that fragment, is able to attach that fragment to itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I downloaded sample project from github. This project had

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
targetSdkVersion 23
```

in Activity `context` and `findViewById()` were in red color inside onCreate() method. So I updated the above versions to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
targetSdkVersion 25
```

and error got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question in Android studio learning,just because I create the project by `Fragment`. Choose `Blank Activity` with no `Fragment` would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by changing targetSdkVersion from 23 to 21

Answer (score 0):

Add `getView()` before `findViewById()` method.

Like this:

`getView().findViewById(R.id.potatoes);`

Comment: A question that is not working. And now I also noticed that my own getView() is not working.

Answer (score -1):

getActivity().findViewById()
This works it removes the red colour of findviewby id and it doesnt say cannot resolve symbol but when i put a colin in the end the whole statement is underlined and it says unreachable statement.
barChart =(BarChart)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.barchart);
I am also doing this in fragment.

Answer (score -2):

This is how you can solve the problem:

```
toggleButton1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);  
toggleButton2=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification